# Посоветуйте текстовый редактор

Tags: редактор, редактор-текста

Возникла следующая проблема. Мне нужна выделять текст следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данный скриншот сделан в Notepad++ и этот редактор отлично справляется с этой функцией. Но есть одна проблема. Когда закрываешь файл - все стили пропадают. В ворде же мы можем сохранить файл с выделенным цветным текстом и пользоваться им, но минус ворда для меня в том, что нет эффекта словно ты пишешь программный код - нет вот этого блока с цифрами слева, который есть в Notepad++.

Вот я и хочу найти редактор, который объединял бы эти две функции:
    1. Интерфейс рабочей области как в Notepad++
    2. Выделение текста цветом, как в word

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что-то подходящее

Comment: В текстовом файле нельзя сохранить форматирование. Или это будет уже не текстовый файл.

Comment: В формате docx сохраняется

Comment: ну изобретите html

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-remove-line-numbers-b67cd35e-422c-42eb-adc9-256ca9802e22